# Encryption On SSD Curiosity

Tags: encryption, ssd

I was curious if encryption of any kind is bad for an SSD.

I recently read up on disk encryption on SSDs and found out that it's not good for it. But is encryption such as password managers (KeepassX, Seahorse), photovaults, bad for it also, the encryption keys are stored locally so isn't that the same somewhat? And what about PGP and along those lines? Should I worry about encryption on my SSD of any kind?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this post:
https://superuser.com/questions/448965/does-full-disk-encryption-on-ssd-drive-reduce-its-lifetime

In resume:

No it's not bad, not really. 
In practice, your SSD will just be unable to compress some of the data you send to him (So your encrypted data will take more place and so use the disk "faster")

Also you should verify your encryption program use block cypher (like Truecrypt) and not stream cypher.

So, without this two special cases, yes, you can secure your data without any trouble.